# Python argparse AssertionError when number of arguments exceeds threshold

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to write a Python script with a lot of arguments that I'd like to break up into clear groups using the argparse module as follows:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Placeholder text', add_help=False)
req = parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
req.add_argument('-m','--mode', action='store', dest='mode', help='Operation mode', choices=['single', 'multi'], required=True, metavar='')
req.add_argument('-s','--snps', action='store', dest='snps', help='SNP BED file', required=True, metavar='')
req.add_argument('-r','--reads', action='store', dest='reads', help='Mapped reads file [sam or bam]', required=True, metavar='')
uni = parser.add_argument_group('universal optional arguments')
uni.add_argument('-p','--prefix', action='store', dest='prefix', help='Prefix for temp files and output [Default: TEST]', default='TEST', metavar='')
uni.add_argument('-b','--bam', action='store_true', dest='bam', help='Mapped read file type is bam (auto-detected if *.bam)')
uni.add_argument('-t','--single', action='store_true', dest='single', help='Mapped reads are single-end [Default: False]')
uni.add_argument('-n','--noclean', action='store_true', dest='noclean', help='Do not delete intermediate files (for debuging)')
uni.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', help='show this help message and exit')
mult = parser.add_argument_group('multi(plex) mode arguments')
mult.add_argument('-j','--jobs', action='store', dest='jobs', type=int, help='Divide into # of jobs [Default: 100]', default=100, metavar='')
mult.add_argument('-w','--walltime', action='store', dest='walltime', help='Walltime for each job [Default: 3:00:00]', default='3:00:00', metavar='')
mult.add_argument('-k','--mem', action='store', dest='memory', help='Memory for each job [Default: 5000MB]', default='5000MB', metavar='')
single = parser.add_argument_group('single mode arguments')
single.add_argument('-f','--suffix', action='store', dest='suff', help='Suffix for multiplexed files [set automatically]', default='', metavar='')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

However, when I run this script, with the '-h' option, instead of printing the help text, it spits out the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CountSNPLevelASE.py", line 61, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1688, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1720, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1926, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1866, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1794, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 994, in __call__
    parser.print_help()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2327, in print_help
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2301, in format_help
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 279, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 209, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 330, in _format_usage
    assert ' '.join(opt_parts) == opt_usage
AssertionError
```

The odd thing is that if I comment out ANY of the non-required arguments, I get the proper help text output, like this:

```
usage: CountSNPLevelASE.py -m  -s  -r  [-b] [-t] [-n] [-h] [-j] [-w] [-k] [-f]

Placeholder text

required arguments:
  -m , --mode       Operation mode
  -s , --snps       SNP BED file
  -r , --reads      Mapped reads file [sam or bam]

universal optional arguments:
  -b, --bam         Mapped read file type is bam (auto-detected if *.bam)
  -t, --single      Mapped reads are single-end [Default: False]
  -n, --noclean     Do not delete intermediate files (for debuging)
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit

multi(plex) mode arguments:
  -j , --jobs       Divide into # of jobs [Default: 100]
  -w , --walltime   Walltime for each job [Default: 3:00:00]
  -k , --mem        Memory for each job [Default: 5000MB]

single mode arguments:
  -f , --suffix     Suffix for multiplexed files [set automatically]
```

I can't find a clear explanation for why this is happening. I've tried removing all whitespace to no avail. Any ideas? (I'm using Python 2.7.6 on Mac OS X 10.10.2 if that's helpful).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error with the code you've given on my Ubuntu machine. Python 2.7.8

Comment: As I replied to the comment below: So I played around with it a bit more and discovered that I only see the AssertionError if the script file name is > [11 characters].py . Any 12+ characters causes the error while any <= 11 characters runs fine. I haven't seen this mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in wrapping the usage.  It displays fine when `usage` fits on one line, but fails when it splits it into 2.

There's a known bug issue involving this `assertion`.  The usage formatting code is fragile, and can raise this `assertion` error when there are 'usual' characters in the usage, including  and extra spaces.

It's the `metavar=''` of the 3 required arguments that's giving the problem.  The optional optionals can have a '' metavar.

Notice the double spaces between these arguments in the short usage line?

```
...py -m  -s  -r  [-b]...
```

The `assertion error` is the result of those spaces not making it through the wrapping code intact.

If you can't find suitable alternative metavars for those 3 arguments, then we'll have to figure out how to modify your `argparse` code.  Possibilities include commenting out the assertion statement, or trimming out those extra blanks from the one line usage.  The big fix is a more robust usage formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine on OS X 10.10.2 and Python 2.7.9

I suggest upgrading your Python as Python 2.7.7 contained several argparse related bugfixes, see changelog:

https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/f89216059edf/Misc/NEWS

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I upgraded Python to 2.7.9 and had the same problem. So I played around with it a bit more and discovered that I only see the AssertionError if the script file name is > [11 characters].py . Any 12+ characters causes the error while any <= 11 characters runs fine. I haven't seen this mentioned in the documentation.