# Python argparse AssertionError from metavar `[[USER@]HOST:]FILE`

Tags: python, argparse

Argparse 1.1 or 1.4 fails with `AssertionError` - the weird regex that reads the metavar value seems to blow up argparse - Possibly related to [Python argparse AssertionError when number of arguments exceeds threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29157874/2815)?

Is there any alternative way to create or use the metavar `[[USER@]HOST:]FILE`?

Test setup:

```
$ virtualenv-3.5 --always-copy test2
$ ./test2/bin/pip install argparse
```

Python code test.py:

```
#!/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/python3.5

import os
import sys
print('sys.prefix', sys.prefix)
sys.path.insert(
    0, os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'lib/python3.5/site-packages'))

import argparse
print('argparse', argparse.__version__)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    'files',
    metavar='[[USER@]HOST:]FILE',
    nargs=argparse.PARSER,
    )
parser.add_argument('-a', '-A', metavar='PTRN', dest='patterns', default=[])
parser.add_argument('-b', '-B', metavar='PTRN', dest='patterns', default=[])
parser.add_argument('-c', '-C', metavar='PTRN', dest='patterns', default=[])
parser.add_argument('-d', '-D', metavar='PTRN', dest='patterns', default=[])
parser.add_argument('-e', '-E', metavar='PTRN', dest='patterns', default=[])
parser.add_argument('-f', '-F', metavar='PTRN', dest='patterns', default=[])
print(parser.parse_args())
```

Shell output:

```
$ ./test.py
sys.prefix /Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/..
argparse 1.4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(parser.parse_args())
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1725, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1754, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1971, in _parse_known_args
    self.error(_('too few arguments'))
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 2391, in error
    self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 2353, in print_usage
    self._print_message(self.format_usage(), file)
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 2309, in format_usage
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 306, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 236, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "/Users/[username]/Development/test2/bin/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 358, in _format_usage
    assert ' '.join(pos_parts) == pos_usage
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to create a custom help formatter and do post-processing using a sanitized value.  One way to do so can be like so:

```
class MyHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):

    def _format_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix):
        result = super(MyHelpFormatter, self)._format_usage(
            usage, actions, groups, prefix)
        return result.format(user_host_file='[[USER@]HOST]:FILE')
```

Then construct the parser using the custom formattter

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=MyHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument(
    'files',
    metavar='{user_host_file}',
    nargs=argparse.PARSER,
    )
```

Plugging the rest into the code supplied, something like this is produced

```
$ python demo.py 
('argparse', '1.1')
usage: demo.py [-h] [-a PTRN] [-b PTRN] [-c PTRN] [-d PTRN] [-e PTRN]
               [-f PTRN]
               [[USER@]HOST]:FILE ...
demo.py: error: too few arguments
```

Naturally, the exact strategy can be as simple as using the `str.replace` method in the formatter, or more complicated than the `str.format` method.

Comment: Nice hack - you also need to override the method `_format_action_invocation` to complete the hack.

Comment: Cool.  Yeah this is a pain, my most recent project has a ~200 line long module that workaround/augment the deficiencies in this module across all supported versions of Python; bug fixes between 2.7 and 3.3 (and maybe 3.5) can result in various different/unexpected behaviours.

Comment: Discovered something else - need to override the method `ArgumentParser.error` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a known bug in the `argparse` `usage` formatter.  Characters in the metavar like brackets produce this assertion error.  I could point out the bug/issue or explain the problem.  But the simplest solution is to just change your `METAVAR` to something simpler.  Put the extra information in the help line.  Another simple option is to provide a custom `usage` parameter.

http://bugs.python.org/issue11874

Subclassing the `HelpFormatter` and replacing one or two methods is also good `argparse` practice.  But that requires digging into the code, and understanding what needs to be replaced.  The other answer is a good start.  The changes suggest in the issue patch are more complicated because it is trying to be general purpose (including the handling of mutually exclusive groups and usage that can span several lines).

Comment: Ah you found the bug issue thanks - my google-foo failed me! I knew the source of the problem was a regex in `_format_usage` - the trick is how to fix the class without rewriting couple hundred lines of code from `argparse`

Comment: The assertion is used to make sure it is splitting the usage string correctly.  But the splitting is only used in the multiline case.  If usage fits on one line, this splitting isn't needed.  My big-patch created a list of usage strings, only joining them into one at the end.