# argparse AssertionError with metavar having square brackets

Tags: python, argparse

Below is some example code that shows an interesting case where three independently working lines of code do not work when run together but do work if you change the flag name strings to something simpler like "-a","-b", etc or if you comment out any one of the individual flags. The usage for the test script is included in the test script's external parser which launches the various internal experimental parsers. Parsers a, b, and c are all identical but have one flag commented out each. The help for these parsers all work. The broken parser is also identical to the others execept all flags are now active (not commented).

I don't really know why this is the case because the flags should be independent objects of each other with their own memory allocations and everything so enabling one option shouldn't break the others. Strangely, if you just change random bits of either the flag name or the bit with '[lin]|log', this also fixes it. This is illustrated with parser d.

I would report this as a bug but I don't know what part is actually broken, my code or argparse. The error when it fails is not very helpful at identifying this but I kind of suspect something is wrong with argparse.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
from pdb import set_trace as br
mainparser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='select whether to work or fail')
mainparser.add_argument('p',action='store',type=str,metavar='[working_a|working_b|working_c|working_d|broken]', help='Type "working_a" or "working_b" or "working_c" or "working_d" or "broken" to see the parser succeed or fail')

working_parser_a=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='a')
# working_parser_a.add_argument('-cmap',metavar='hot_desaturated',nargs=1,default='hot_desaturated',help='Colormap to use for colorbar')
working_parser_a.add_argument('-cbar_scale',metavar='[lin]|log',nargs=1,type=str,default='lin',help='Linear or log scale colormap')
working_parser_a.add_argument('-title',metavar='The Plot Title',type=str,nargs=1,help='Define the plot title that goes above the plot')

working_parser_b=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='b')
working_parser_b.add_argument('-cmap',metavar='hot_desaturated',nargs=1,default='hot_desaturated',help='Colormap to use for colorbar')
# working_parser_b.add_argument('-cbar_scale',metavar='[lin]|log',nargs=1,type=str,default='lin',help='Linear or log scale colormap')
working_parser_b.add_argument('-title',metavar='The Plot Title',type=str,nargs=1,help='Define the plot title that goes above the plot')

working_parser_c=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='c')
working_parser_c.add_argument('-cmap',metavar='hot_desaturated',nargs=1,default='hot_desaturated',help='Colormap to use for colorbar')
working_parser_c.add_argument('-cbar_scale',metavar='[lin]|log',nargs=1,type=str,default='lin',help='Linear or log scale colormap')
# working_parser_c.add_argument('-title',metavar='The Plot Title',type=str,nargs=1,help='Define the plot title that goes above the plot')

broken_parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='e')
broken_parser.add_argument('-cmap',metavar='hot_desaturated',help='')
broken_parser.add_argument('-cbar_scale',metavar='[lin]|log',default='lin',help='')
broken_parser.add_argument('-title',metavar='The Plot Title',help='')

working_parser_d=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='d')
working_parser_d.add_argument('-a',metavar='hot_desaturated',nargs=1,default='hot_desaturated',help='Colormap to use for colorbar')
working_parser_d.add_argument('-b',metavar='[lin]|log',nargs=1,type=str,default='lin',help='Linear or log scale colormap')
working_parser_d.add_argument('-c',metavar='The Plot Title',type=str,nargs=1,help='Define the plot title that goes above the plot')

args=mainparser.parse_args()
if args.p=='working_a':
    working_parser_a.parse_args(['-h'])
elif args.p=='working_b':
    working_parser_b.parse_args(['-h'])
elif args.p=='working_c':
    working_parser_c.parse_args(['-h'])
elif args.p=='working_d':
    working_parser_d.parse_args(['-h'])
elif args.p=='broken':
    broken_parser.parse_args(['-h'])
else:
    p=args.p
    print("The argument "+p+" is not a valid parser",file=sys.stderr)
    mainparser.parse_args(['-h'])
```

Outputs:
working parser a:

```
ζ python test.py working_a
usage: test.py [-h] [-cbar_scale [lin]|log] [-title The Plot Title]

a

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -cbar_scale [lin]|log
                         Linear or log scale colormap
  -title The Plot Title
                         Define the plot title that goes above the plot
```

working parser b:

```
ζ python test.py working_b
usage: test.py [-h] [-cmap hot_desaturated] [-title The Plot Title]

b

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -cmap hot_desaturated
                        Colormap to use for colorbar
  -title The Plot Title
                        Define the plot title that goes above the plot
```

working parser c:

```
ζ python test.py working_c
usage: test.py [-h] [-cmap hot_desaturated] [-cbar_scale [lin]|log]

c

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -cmap hot_desaturated
                        Colormap to use for colorbar
  -cbar_scale [lin]|log
                        Linear or log scale colormap
```

working d:

```
ζ python test.py working_d
usage: test.py [-h] [-a hot_desaturated] [-b [lin]|log] [-c The Plot Title]

d

optional arguments:
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit
  -a hot_desaturated  Colormap to use for colorbar
  -b [lin]|log        Linear or log scale colormap
  -c The Plot Title   Define the plot title that goes above the plot
```

Broken:

```
ζ python test.py broken
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
    broken_parser.parse_args(['-h'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1703, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1735, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1941, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1881, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1809, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 1015, in __call__
    parser.print_help()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 2328, in print_help
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 2302, in format_help
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 300, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 230, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py", line 351, in _format_usage
    assert ' '.join(opt_parts) == opt_usage
AssertionError
```

Comment: At the moment, your question is very unclear. Please try to add some information to define your exact problem.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace. The error message may not be useful to you, but we may be able to make sense of it. And what do you mean by "name strings"?

Comment: This is interesting... You seem to be hitting an assertion deep in argparse itself and so this is likely a bug of some sort in argparse.  Also, running python with `-O` (which just removes the assertion) seems to make it work again...

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue11874 -- not quite the same thing, but related inasmuch as it shows other special-casing with square brackets causing trouble.

Comment: ...frankly, coming up with a shorter and more focused reproducer (see the ones in the ticket, which generally comply with our [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rules) would improve this question substantially. Likewise, including the exception and stack trace in the question itself.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can shorten the reproducer and still provide all examples of the different behaviors. The majority of the code is just three lines replicated with minor variations I would otherwise ask people to manually change. I can change the strings filling in metavar and descriptions to something a little shorter but that's a fiddly process because changing them too much fixes the problem and the exact break point isn't known and finding it is part of the problem.

Comment: @amoose136, ...part of why I point to the examples in the ticket is that they did a good job of that -- `'o'*76` to generate a long string (f'rinstance) demonstrates very clearly that the length is not incidental from code that's copy/pasted but part of the immediate cause and thus necessary to reproduce.

Comment: @amoose136 you don't need to include all the different examples. I reduced it to just including the import of argparse, parser_a without anything commented out (so it's now broken), and your parser_a call to `parse_args(['-h'])`. Then in a couple of bullet points you can include your observations: it doesn't occur with <3 arguments, or if the brackets are removed from metavar, or if it is run with -O, etc. People will experiment on their own.

Comment: Same error and issue a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008269/python-argparse-assertionerror-from-metavar-userhostfile

Comment: The basic fix is - avoid brackets and other special characters in the `metavar`.  Yes, the usage formater is clunkier than it needs to be.

Comment: there's a [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/1826) pending to fix this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in argparse related to how you are using the `metavar` variable.  Here's some helpful information for tracking this down...

First, seems to happen when you have a `metavar` with `'['` or `']'` characters in it.

Second, it seems to be dependent on the number of arguments (more than 2 trigger the problem).  The actual *number* of arguments might be a read herring -- It could be related to whether the formatter needs to split the arguments onto multiple lines or something else which is loosely coupled to the number of arguments...

Third, this is an `AssertionError` raised at an `assert` statement.  We can run the code with `-O` and see what happens:

```
$ python3 -O ~/sandbox/ap.py broken
usage: ap.py [-h] [-cmap hot_desaturated] [-title The Plot Title]
             [-cbar_scale [lin] |log]
<snip>
```

And we can see on the last line that our `[lin]|log` has been split into `[lin] |log` which is probably why the assertion is failing.

---

So, I would say that this is likely to be a low priority bug in `argparse`.  And it [*may* already be reported](https://bugs.python.org/issue11874) as pointed out by @CharlesDuffy in the comments.

Note that you're better off using `choices=...` for validating the inputs to an argument.  When you do that, argparse will create a somewhat suitable metavar for you:

```
broken_parser.add_argument('-cbar_scale',default='lin', type=str, nargs=1, help='', choices=('lin', 'log'))
```

results in:

```
usage: ap.py [-h] [-cmap hot_desaturated] [-title The Plot Title]
             [-cbar_scale {lin,log}]
```

This isn't *quite* as nice (it doesn't tell you what the default is for example), but you can easily put that in the `help` string.  If really necessary, you can use curly brackets for the metavar:  `metavar='{{lin}|log}'` and that works just fine...

Comment: I'll see if I can change to the "choices=..." convention.